# How to get this jQuery code to work on identical html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dry

I'd like to use a single jQuery code for all my div elements with the class of `TextWrapper`, but I'm not sure how to do that. The jQuery code flickers between two different divs with the strings "`Text`" and "`MoreText`". But the code I'm using only works on the first element and not the sequential ones. I can only get it to work by making duplicates of the jQuery code and by editing the `.TextWrapper` title, but it would be tedious and repetitive doing this knowing there is a shorthand.

This is my jQuery code; the second function is a copy of the first, except for the change in the `.TextWrapper` title:

```
$(function(){
    $(".TextWrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        var current = $('.TextWrapper div:visible');
        var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('.TextWrapper div:eq(0)');
        current.fadeOut(500);
        next.fadeIn(500);
    }, 1000);
});  

$(function(){
    $(".TextWrapper2 div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        var current = $('.TextWrapper2 div:visible');
        var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('.TextWrapper2 div:eq(0)');
        current.fadeOut(500);
        next.fadeIn(500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

How can I shorten this code into a single jQuery code so that it works on all my html elements with an identical code? I've also added my html and css, thank you for your help

```js
$(function(){
 "use strict";
 $(".TextWrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
 setInterval(function(){
  var current = $('.TextWrapper div:visible');
  var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('.TextWrapper div:eq(0)');
  current.fadeOut(500);
  next.fadeIn(500);
 }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.Border {
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-flex;
 height: 110px;
}
.Img {
 width: 75px;
 height:75px;
}
.TextWrapper {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.TextWrapper div {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Border">
 <div class="ImgAndText"> 
  <img src="#" class="Img">
  <div class="TextWrapper">
   <div>Text</div>
   <div>MoreText</div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>

<div class="Border">
 <div class="ImgAndText"> 
  <img src="#" class="Img">
  <div class="TextWrapper">
   <div>Text</div>
   <div>MoreText</div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: You are running code for only one `TextWrapper` div. User `.each()` which will consider all `TextWrapper` div one by one. See below code

```js
$(function(){
 "use strict";
 $(".TextWrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
 setInterval(function(){
       $('.TextWrapper').each(function(){
  var current = $(this).find('div:visible');
  var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $(this).find('div:first');
  current.fadeOut(500);
  next.fadeIn(500);
     });
 }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.Border {
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-flex;
 height: 110px;
}
.Img {
 width: 75px;
 height:75px;
}
.TextWrapper {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.TextWrapper div {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Border">
 <div class="ImgAndText"> 
  <img src="#" class="Img">
  <div class="TextWrapper">
   <div>Text</div>
   <div>MoreText</div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>

<div class="Border">
 <div class="ImgAndText"> 
  <img src="#" class="Img">
  <div class="TextWrapper">
   <div>Text</div>
   <div>MoreText</div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed - a function with an each() method. I was just very confused on how to implement that into my code. Thank you very much, you're a life saver!!

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can multiple jQuery selectors in one query: `$(".TextWrapper div:gt(0), .TextWrapper div:gt(0)")`